# PIE.htc not working on different web server

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css3pie

I can't quite figure out why. But I have some code which uses PIE.htc and works fine @ http://www.supadupawebdesign.co.uk/jersey but when I stick it on a different server it doesn't work: http://www.jerseyisland.co.uk

Any ideas why this isn't working? Just seems a bit weird like its a server setting or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your new server is sending `PIE.htc` with this HTTP response header, which breaks it:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

The fix to this problem is detailed in the CSS3 PIE documentation:

http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#content-type